# How to optimize my sql query?

Tags: sql, select, query-optimization

```
SELECT ORG.DESCRIPTION, ORG.EXTERNALKEY,
   (SELECT P.VALUE FROM PROPERTY P, ORGANIZATION ORG WHERE P.IDX=24 AND ORG.ID=P.ID AND ORG.EXTERNALKEY='200004') AS COR_ACCOUNT,
   (SELECT ORG.DESCRIPTION FROM ORGANIZATION ORG WHERE ORG.NAME = P.VALUE) AS CPC,
   (SELECT P.VALUE FROM PROPERTY P, ORGANIZATION ORG WHERE P.IDX = 4 AND P.ID = ORG.ID AND ORG.EXTERNALKEY = '200004') AS VOEN
FROM PROPERTY P, ORGANIZATION ORG
WHERE P.IDX = 22 AND ORG.EXTERNALKEY = '200004' AND P.ID = ORG.ID;
```

Hi. How to optimize this sql or is this normal?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve with the query you posted with the table structures and sample data? It is too hard to understand the query you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your exact requirement but given SQL i think below should work.

```
SELECT ORG.DESCRIPTION, ORG.EXTERNALKEY,
CASE WHEN P.IDX = 24 then P.Value END AS COR_ACCOUNT,
(SELECT ORG.DESCRIPTION FROM ORGANIZATION ORG WHERE ORG.NAME = P.VALUE) AS CPC,
  CASE WHEN p.idx = 4 then P.VALUE END AS VOEN
FROM PROPERTY P, ORGANIZATION ORG
WHERE P.IDX in(22,24,4) AND ORG.EXTERNALKEY = '200004' AND P.ID = ORG.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It'l Optimize your query

```
SELECT ORG.DESCRIPTION,ORG.EXTERNALKEY,
CASE WHEN ORG.EXTERNALKEY='200004' AND P.IDX=24 THEN P.VALUE END AS COR_ACCOUNT,
(SELECT ORG.DESCRIPTION FROM ORGANIZATION ORG WHERE ORG.NAME = P.VALUE) AS CPC,
CASE WHEN ORG.EXTERNALKEY='200004' AND P.IDX=4 THEN P.VALUE END AS VOEN,
FROM PROPERTY P, ORGANIZATION ORG
WHERE P.IDX = 22 AND ORG.EXTERNALKEY = '200004' AND P.ID = ORG.ID;
```